# Getting a Result from an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

To describe the situation, say that I have 3 activities: A, B, and C
and there is a button in activity A which starts activity B, and there is a button in activity C when it is clicked, it should send a result from activity C to activity A

My Question is...Is there a way to pass a result from C to A? If there is a way, what it is?

Note: It would be good if the way you give uses the methods startActivityForResult(...) and onActivityResult(...)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you use a database (e.g. Firebase) to store that result? And retrieve it from activity C?

Comment: @CatalinGhita I can do that, but I want to get the result immediately when the result is passed, by using a code or a method like onActivityResult()

Answer (score 1):

There's a flag of `Intent` called [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT). Call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActiivtyForResult(intent);
```

when starting `Activity` B (by calling `startActivityForResult(intent)`).
When opening C, call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActiivtyForResult(intent);
finish();
```

which means: open C, close B. Then, when closing Acitivity C, call:

```
setResult(123);
finish();
```

the result from C will go back to A.

Comment: You meant that I should add this line of code in activity B in onClick() method?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand, can you explain it in more details?

Answer (score 1):

If you just using simple types like String objects you can use Bundle and supplementary variables in B,C activities. And transfer it from C->B->A using onActivity result. Or you could  use Shared preferences.

Comment: It is good idea. However, I want to pass it from C to A immediately

Comment: Make your result in activity C then send result to shared preference and call activity A and ger result from shared preferences

Comment: I want to execute a code when the result is passed, by using a code or a method like onActivityResult().

Comment: I think "intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT)

when starting Activity B (by calling startActivityForResult(intent)) and C. When opening C, close B. Then the result from C will go back to A."  answer is best fit for you. In manual "int FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT

If set and this intent is being used to launch a new activity from an existing one, then the reply target of the existing activity will be transfered to the new activity. This way the new activity can call setResult(int) and have that result sent back to the reply target of the original activity. "

Comment: Could you please give me an example(a Code)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intent` to transfer data if you are navigating from `Activity C` to `Activity A`. Otherwise, I would suggest using an `Interface`, and then pass the data as parameter in a `callback` method present in `Activity A`. You said you wanted answers like `onActivityResult`, for that I guess the `Activity C` should exit or something to invoke `onActivityResult` in the `Activity A`